# Is there a Live ISO image for the Debian Server?

Tags: debian, iso

I'm not sure if it's proper enough as a separate question but I don't seem to be able to find a Debian Server Live ISO image, I've searched for it without success. Maybe it doesn't exist at all?
The ISO images listed [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/) all seem to have desktops with them which I don't want, or is the one listed [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/release/current/amd64/iso-cd/) which doesn't seem to be Live. By "Live" I mean I want to have it booted from the DVD-ROM without needing to install it. I've tried the netinst version already but when it's booted it only has "Install" options and no live run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The “standard” live image](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-10.5.0-amd64-standard.iso) provides this: it’s a live image which boots to a console prompt, with no desktop environment installed.

This isn’t “Debian Server” because there is no such thing, but it’s a minimal installation of Debian, and should serve the same purpose as the “Server” variant of other distributions.